# If I compile Tor to use 2 hops circuits, will it make 2 hops circuits to non-anonymous hidden services?

Tags: onion-services, circuit

I know that Tor introduced options for setting up a non-anonymous hidden service, [Cloudflare hidden resolver](https://blog.cloudflare.com/welcome-hidden-resolver/#:%7E:text=How%20does%20the%20Cloudflare%20hidden,internal%20IP%20rather%20than%20yours.) is an example of a non-anonymous one.

I built a Tor binary to use 2 hops circuits for browsing speed, will it use 2 hops circuit to connect to non-anonymous hidden services or will it use 3 hops?

Answer (score 1):

The connections are **made**, so the ones you're asking about will be *just made* in the very same way. Reducing hop length rips off your anonymity, you must know...

Comment: This is exactly what I do, I have Tor executables for making 2 hops connections for Linux and Windows. I use them for things that don't need a great level of anonymity such as casual browsing.